# Form that reveals more fields as each step has been completed

Tags: javascript, beginner, jquery, validation, form

I'm new to JavaScript and jQuery and need input about how to optimize my script:

```
(document).ready(function() {

    var inputs_1 = $("form#myForm .case1 input, form#myForm .case1 select");
    var inputs_2 = $("form#myForm .case2 input, form#myForm .case2 select");
    var inputs_3 = $("form#myForm .case3 input");

    $("form#myForm .case2").addClass("disabled");
    $("form#myForm .case3").addClass("disabled");
    $("form#myForm .case2 input, form#myForm .case2 select").prop('disabled', true);
    $("form#myForm .case3 input").prop('disabled', true);

    var validateInputs = function validateInputs(inputs) {
      var validForm = true;
      inputs.each(function(index) {
        var input = $(this);
        if (!input.val()) {
            $("#subnewtide").prop('disabled', true);
            validForm = false;
        }
      });
      return validForm;
    }


    inputs_1.change(function() {
      if (validateInputs(inputs_1)) {
          $("form#myForm .case2").removeClass('disabled');
          $("form#myForm .case2 input, form#myForm .case2 select").prop('disabled', false);
      }
    });

    inputs_2.change(function() {
      if (validateInputs(inputs_2)) {
          $("form#myForm .case3").removeClass('disabled');
          $("form#myForm .case3 input").prop('disabled', false);
      }
    });

    inputs_3.change(function() {
      if (validateInputs(inputs_3)) {
          $("#subnewtide").prop('disabled', false);
      }
    });

});
```

It is a registration form. After a user has inserted all inputs from step1 the next step should be shown. so far so good. My solution works, but I guess it is not the best way to solve my issue.

How can I abstract this more to increase maintainability?

I need a way to use one XY.change(function) handler, not for everyone a single solution.

Comment: I think it would be enough for form validation use some jsplugin for example [this](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) or you can find some inspiration in it.

Comment: it is not a validation. yes i check is it empty or not, but for this i dont want to use a plugin with 100mb. it should be simple, thats all.

Comment: I assume there is a missing `$` at the start of the code?

Comment: Find some improvements [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/xzzdot3v/). [Edit] the question to add corresponding HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Code is pretty neat, though you might consider a couple of additional objectives :

- ensuring that elements are re-disabled if the user revisits an earlier form field and makes it invalid.
- allowing the validate/disable/enable system to work with as many cases as might appear in the form, without needing to amend the javascript.

I guess there are many ways these objectives could be met.

Here's one way, in which :

- the key actions ('validate' and 'disable') are written as custom event handlers. That proves to be very convenient as it allows elements to be given behaviours that can be triggered *en bloc* without needing to write jQuery plugins or loop manually in the high level application code.
- several assumptions are made about the HTML/DOM_tree, in particular that `.case1`, `.case3`, `.case3` select one element each.

**HTML**

Add class name `case` to all "case" containers.

**JavaScript**

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var $cases = $('.case'),
        $finalElement = $('#subnewtide'),
        $casesPlus = $cases.add($finalElement)
        fieldSelector = 'input, select'; // a reusable selector string

    // attach event handlers to $cases
    $cases.on('validate', function(event) { // custom event
        var $this = $(this),
            n = $this.index($cases), // index of this within $cases
            valid = true;
        $casesPlus.slice(n+1).trigger('disable', [true]); // unconditionally disable everything below `this`
        $(this).find(fieldSelector).each(function() {
            if (!$(this).val()) {
                valid = false;
                return false; // break out of .each() iteration
            }
        });
        if (valid) {
            // conditionally enable next case and trigger 'validate' on it ... and so on in cascade ...
            $casesPlus.slice(n+1, n+2).trigger('disable', [false]).trigger('validate');
        }
    }).on('disable', function(event, bool) { // custom event
        if (bool) {
            $(this).addClass('disabled').find(fieldSelector).prop('disabled', true);
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('disabled').find(fieldSelector).prop('disabled', false);
        }
    }).on('change', fieldSelector, function(event) {
        $(this).closest('.case').trigger('validate');
    });

    // attach event handlers to $finalElement
    // (slightly different from $cases)
    $finalElement.on('disable', function(event, bool) {
        $(this).prop('disabled', bool);
    });

    // initially, enable the first case and trigger 'validate' to disable everything else.
    $cases.eq(0).trigger('disable', [false]).trigger('validate');
});
```

*untested*

This style of programming tends to suit form validation and spreadsheet-like applications.

Comment: In the `disable` event handler, instead of `if ... else`, you can use `$(this).toggleClass('disabled', bool).find(fieldSelector).prop('disabled', bool)`.

Comment: Yes, that would be more concise.

Answer (score 1):

Nice work.

You can make a lot of headway by using `data-*` attributes. These are attributes you can add to any element to store whatever you want in them. They will be available on the `.dataset` property of the HTMLElement, and will always have string values. For instance, given the following HTMLELment:

```html
<div id="some-elm" data-hello-world="JohnDoo" />
```

You could access the value of the `data-hello-world` attribute via:

```js
const elm = document.querySelector('#some-elm');
console.log(elm.dataset.helloWold);
// -> "JohnDoo"
```

- [Definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*): `data-*`
- [Resulting property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset): `HTMLElement.dataset`
- [Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)

With that, you can generalize what you're doing with your handlers. On each case, you can store the case number (1, 2, 3, 4) in a `data-case="N"` attribute, and store the following case in another attribute `data-next-case="N+1"`.

```html
<section class="js-case" data-case="1" data-next-case="2">
  ...
</section>
```

This allows you to write one change (actually, "input" event) handler.

```ks
function onInput() {
  if (!isCaseValid(this)) {
    return;
  }
  const nextId = this.dataset.nextCase;
  const $nextCase = $form.find(`[data-case=${nextId}]`);
  $nextCase
    .removeClass('disabled')
    .find('.js-form-field')
    .prop('disabled', false);
}
```

You'll notice I'm using classes of the form `js-*` like `js-form-field`, that's because it's nice to separate CSS class names that are used purely for JS from those used for styling ([more info](http://nicolasgallagher.com/about-html-semantics-front-end-architecture/#javascript-specific-classes)).

The full JavaScript:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  function isCaseValid(caseElm) {
    let isValid = true;
    $(caseElm).find('.js-form-field').each(function() {
        isValid = isValid && Boolean(this.value);
    });
    return isValid;
  }

  function onInput() {
    if (!isCaseValid(this)) {
      return;
    }
    const nextId = this.dataset.nextCase;
    const $nextCase = $form.find(`[data-case=${nextId}]`);
    $nextCase
      .removeClass('disabled')
      .find('.js-form-field')
      .prop('disabled', false);
  }

  const $form = $('#register-form');  
  $form.find('.js-case').on('input', onInput);

});
```

And, the HTML to go with it:

```html
<form id="register-form">
  <section class="js-case" data-case="1" data-next-case="2">
    <input type="text" class="js-form-field">
    <select class="js-form-field">
      <option value>select an option</option>
      <option value="hello">hello</option>
      <option value="world">world</option>
    </select>
  </section>
  <section class="disabled js-case" data-case="2" data-next-case="3">
    <input type="text" class="js-form-field" disabled>
    <select class="js-form-field" disabled>
      <option value>select an option</option>
      <option value="hello">hello</option>
      <option value="world">world</option>
    </select>
  </section>
  <section class="disabled js-case" data-case="3" data-next-case="4">
    <input type="text" class="js-form-field" disabled>
    <select class="js-form-field" disabled>
      <option value>select an option</option>
      <option value="hello">hello</option>
      <option value="world">world</option>
    </select>
  </section>
  <section class="disabled js-case" data-case="4">
    <button class="js-form-field" disabled>
      submit
    </button>
  </section>
</form>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oerk5deu/